# How to create Checkbox with label on the left and styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, stylesheet

I've seen a visual design like below:

[image]

basically it is a checkbox (with label on the left, and styled border and all...) works as a filter.
I don't wanna reinvent the wheels but after half-day googling I found nothing fit or near to this design. 
First obstacle is move the label to the left which is normally on the right. Furthermore, the styling is pretty painful if using pure CSS.

So I would ask your help on this, would you please provide some idea? any idea will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hang on is it the layout that you're struggling with, or the...interaction coloring?

Comment: @Piyush For get to mention, yes I'm using dotnet. I purely thought it was an js/css/html issue.

Comment: if you are using dotnet, then this is very simple, there is no need for js or any css to display text on left hand side. for improve display, css required.

Comment: @DavidThomas, both, however I think I should be able to handle interaction coloring one layout is solved

Comment: @Piyush would you please be a little bit more specific?

Comment: You need to just use this simple code to display text in left side of checkbox  <asp:CheckBox ID="testCheckbox" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" Text="Test Me" />.... Further, if you need display good, then use css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this comes pretty close to your screenshot. [Here's a fiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net/crrc7s7f/3/).

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px 52px 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.checkbox::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 37px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.checkbox::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    content: '';
    float: left;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 4px;
    border: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: url(http://dev.instinkt.dk/checkmark.png);
    background-size: 26px 52px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox {
    border: 1px solid #4575ab;
    color: #4575ab;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox::before {
    background-color: #4575ab;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox::after {
    border: 1px solid #4575ab;
    background-color: #4575ab;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<input id="mycheckbox1" type="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox" for="mycheckbox1">Custom checkbox</label>
<br>
<input id="mycheckbox2" type="checkbox" checked>
<label class="checkbox" for="mycheckbox2">Custom checkbox</label>
```

Comment: This would be incorrect according to W3C ...

Placing DIV inside LABEL is invalid

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the code example and the fiddle to use spans instead of divs.

Comment: @ostrgard, thanks a lot! closest approach in terms of layout. However there seems a bug, can't click the same spot continuously.

Comment: @noru, actually I have the same issue with the accepted answer. It's due to the OS trying to make a selection. Adding `user-select: none` to the label fixes this. I've updated my answer, just in case you want to use it. Removed the span element inside the label element as well. Anyway - glad you found a solution to your problem :)

Comment: @ostrgard, I found that too about 10 sec later...  really appreciated for your fix!

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this with **CSS only**, using your regular `checkbox` and `label` without **wrappers** or **images** or anything else. Although not exactly like what you have in those images.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
label {
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
    display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}
label::after {
    content: '\2713';
    padding: 8px; margin-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px dashed #ccc; 
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid #4575ab;
    color: #4575ab;
    
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    border: 1px solid #fff; 
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #4575ab;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<br /><br />
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk1">Category 1</label>
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk2">Category 2</label>
<input id="chk3" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk3">Category 3</label>
```

---

### Update:

Here is another one which is much much closer to the images you have in your question. Again, *does not require use of any images*. And, very concise code. Now, also takes care of the selection issue when double-clicking.

***Snippet 2:***

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
label {
    position: relative;
    height: 38px; line-height: 36px; 
    margin: 4px; padding: 0px 4px 0px 8px;
    display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;    
}
label::before {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    top: 0px; right: 32px;
    height: 36px; width: 2px;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}
label::after {
    content: '\2713'; text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12px; 
    display: inline-block; border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px dashed #999;
    height: 26px; line-height: 26px; width: 24px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid #4575ab;
    color: #4575ab;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    border: 1px solid #4575ab; 
    background-color: #4575ab;
    color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
    border-left: 1px solid #4575ab;
}
```

```html
<br /><br />
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk1">Category 1</label>
<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" checked /><label for="chk2">Category 2</label>
<input id="chk3" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk3">Category 3</label>
```

***Demo Fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mxkqq4Lg/3/***

.

Comment: Uh, like this solution, too

Comment: Omg, thanks and accepted! Also many thanks to other answers, very inspiring!

Answer (score 2):

I would create DIV container for each thing ...

Like

```
<div class="option">
  <div class="label">Category 1</div>
  <div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="category_1" class="hidden" />
</div>
```

Hide the checkbox via css, style the boxes via css.

Via jQuery you handle the clicks

```
$('.option').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("checked") {
    $(this).removeClass("checked");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("checked");
  }
  $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").click();
});
```

Within your CSS do something like this:

```
.option .box { background-image: url('unchecked.jpg'); }
.option.checked .box { background-image: url('checked.jpg'); }
```

Note: Untested, just some idea